# How to get data from Arduino USB Serial Port when the app is in the background?

Tags: android, service, arduino, broadcastreceiver, job-scheduling

This post will be long because I'm trying to explain the full scenario of my problem. Please read it patiently.

Now, I'm trying to control the app features using some physical buttons connected to Arduino. To connect the Arduino to a mobile device I'm using an OTG cable.

I have three activities. One is a splash activity, which is launcher one. The other two are Activity1 and Activity2, in which I use this Arduino thing.

So now I've made a broadcast receiver for system actions i.e., USB Permission, USB Attached and USB Detached. I wrote the broadcast receiver in the activities itself separately. And I register the receiver when the activity is created i.e., in `onCreate()`. That goes for both the activities. And I unregister the receiver when the activity is destroyed.

In the broadcast receiver's `onReceive()` method, I write the code like this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  //Broadcast Receiver to automatically start and stop the Serial connection.
  @Override
  @AddTrace(name = "broadcast receiver", enabled = true/*Optional*/)
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
      boolean granted = intent.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
      Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, String.valueOf(granted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      device = (UsbDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
      if (granted) {
        connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
        serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
        if (serialPort != null) {
          if (serialPort.open()) {
            //Set Serial Connection Parameters.
            serialPort.setBaudRate(9600);
            serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
            serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
            serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
            serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
            serialPort.read(mCallback);
            Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, "Port Opening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
            Log.d("SERIAL", "PORT NOT OPEN");
            Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, "PORT NOT OPEN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } else {
            Log.d("SERIAL", "PORT IS NULL");
            Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, "PORT IS NULLg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
        } else {
          Log.d("SERIAL", "PERM NOT GRANTED");
          Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, "PERM NOT GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)) {
        onClickStart();
      } else if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED)) {
        onClickStop();
        finish();
      }
    };
  };

  UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
      String data;
      try {
        data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");
        final String finalData = data;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            switch (finalData) {
              case "portopen":
                break;
              case "portinc":
                System.exit(0);
                break;
              case "scan":
                onClickStop();
                requestPicture();
                break;
              case "lang":
                counter++;
                counter = counter % 3;
              if (counter == 0) {
                ImageNameSingleton.getInstance().setLanguage("eng");
                textToSpeech.speak("English selected", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHash1);
              } else if (counter == 1) {
                ImageNameSingleton.getInstance().setLanguage("hin");
                textToSpeech.speak("Hindi Selected", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHash1);
              } else if (counter == 2) {
                ImageNameSingleton.getInstance().setLanguage("mar");
                textToSpeech.speak("Marathi Selected", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHash1);
              }
              break;
            default:
              break;
          }
        }
      });
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } //Defining a Callback which triggers whenever data is read.
};

@AddTrace(name = "onClickstart", enabled = true/*Optional*/)
public void onClickStart() {
  Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, "onClickStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
  if (!usbDevices.isEmpty()) {
    boolean keep = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
      device = entry.getValue();
      int deviceVID = device.getVendorId();
      Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, String.valueOf(deviceVID), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      if (deviceVID == 0x1A86) {
        //Arduino Vendor ID
        Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, "Device Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, String.valueOf(deviceVID) + String.valueOf(device.getProductId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(usbManager.hasPermission(device)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        usbManager.requestPermission(device, pendingintent);
        keep = false;
        connectionEstablished = true;
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(NewCameraActivity.this, "Device Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        connection = null;
        device = null;
      }
      if (!keep) break;
    }
  }
}

private void onClickStop() {
  if(serialPort!=null) serialPort.close();
  else Toast.makeText(this, "No serial port", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Here, when the device is connected to USB, the USB attached action is started and it will start to look for the devices and will search for a particular device with that vendorID. When it gets the device, it will start the USB Permission action to check the permission is given or not. If yes, the code in the USB permission action will be executed. If not, it will ask the user for permission.

Everything is the same for both activities.

Now in Activity1, after the serial port is opened, I will send a string by clicking a button and I receive it in the activity. Based on the string, a particular job will be done (as you can see it in the callback part). After the job (like clicking an image), the data will be sent to Activity2 and the Activity1 will be destroyed along with the receiver.

In Activity2, I will register the receiver again and I'm opening the port again and I'm getting the strings to do jobs.

This is the workflow. Now the problem is, I want the app to open (in the foreground), whether the app is in background or killed, when a button is clicked in Arduino. Also, the app should close when any other button is clicked.

How to do it? Is there any way? Or is my approach not correct? Anyone help me out...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `Services`. Shift your broadcast receivers to a `Service` which runs in the background.